# How can I integrate Cusdis comments in my Docusaurus Website?

Tags: reactjs, comments, documentation, docusaurus

I want to integrate Cusdis Comments in my Docusaurus website.

I tried adding the `react-cusdis@^2.1.3` package via yarn.

```js
yarn add react-cusdis
```

and added the following tags to the pages I wanted to include the comment section in:

```js
import { ReactCusdis } from 'react-cusdis'
```

```html
<head>
  <script async defer src="https://cusdis.com/js/cusdis.es.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="cusdis"
  data-host="https://cusdis.com"
  data-app-id="49da488c-98c0-4284-943e-fc2be8b8504b"
  data-page-id= {frontMatter.id}
  data-page-url= {frontMatter.slug}
  data-page-title= {frontMatter.title}
  data-theme="auto"
></div>
```

When I load the website, the Comments section shows nothing. Only works after reloading.
After adding a Pull Request to the repository, the Vercel Deployment is successful but the comment section shows a blank. Doesn't load after a refresh. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some failed attempts, I have finally been able to do this.

STEP 1: Create a new component for Cusdis as `CusdisComments.js` in the Components folder.

For reference, my component looks something like this:

```js
import { ReactCusdis } from 'react-cusdis'

export default function CusdisComments (props){
  const appId = process.env.CUSDIS_APP_ID;

  return(
    <div>
      <ReactCusdis
        id = "cusdis-thread"
        attrs={{
          host: "https://cusdis.com",
          appId: appId,
          pageId: props.attrs.pageId,
          pageTitle: props.attrs.pageTitle,
          pageUrl: props.attrs.pageUrl,
          theme: "auto",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

STEP 2: Go to the docs page you wish to use this component in. Import the component on top like this:

```js
import CusdisComments from '../src/components/CusdisComments';
```

Then, below on the page where you wish to add the component, add the following:

```
<CusdisComments
  id="cusdis_thread"
  attrs={{
    pageId: frontMatter.id,
    pageTitle: frontMatter.title,
    pageUrl: frontMatter.__resourcePath,
  }} 
/>
```

Also, I have used environment variables to store the Cusdis App Id. So, follow the steps below to set up the environment variables in your Docusaurus Project.

STEP 1: Install the @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects via npm or yarn:

```
npm i @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects
```

or

```
yarn add @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects
```

STEP 2: Go to your docusaurus.config.js file and under the `module.exports` add the following:

```js
plugins: [
      [
        "docusaurus2-dotenv",
        {
          systemvars: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
```

STEP 3: Add a `.env` file and add your Cusdis App Id, like this:

```
CUSDIS_APP_ID = 123456789 // random id
```

STEP 4: Go to your component and use it as follows:

```js
export default function CusdisComments (props){
  const appId = process.env.CUSDIS_APP_ID;

  return(
    <div>
      <ReactCusdis
        id = "cusdis-thread"
        attrs={{
          host: "https://cusdis.com",
          appId: appId,
          pageId: props.attrs.pageId,
          pageTitle: props.attrs.pageTitle,
          pageUrl: props.attrs.pageUrl,
          theme: "auto",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```